# Android how receive more data with onActivityResult

Tags: android, onactivityresult

i start my Dialog Activity with `startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);` for take back some data.
The `protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` can take back only one type of data?

I need to take back a string(from an EditText) and a resource color(Background of a RadioButton)
Can i put all two into `returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);`??
Or can i send only one thing?

This is the code of the Dialog Activity

```
public class ActivityAddMateria extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_materia);

    final Button exit_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit_dialog_materia);
    exit_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //No input
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
            //Exit from Dialog
            finish();
        }
    });

    final Button accept_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_materia);
    accept_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Find EditText for take data
            EditText nome_materia = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nome_materia);
            //Put result into variable result that is send back
            String result = nome_materia.getText().toString();; 

            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
            // Exit to Dialog
            finish();
        }
    });

 }
}
```

And this is the code of the Activity that take the input:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            String result = data.getStringExtra("result");

            Materia materia;
            materia = new Materia();
            materia.setMateria(result);
            materia.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.verde));
            DB.getMaterie().add(materia);

            LinearLayout mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contenitorematerie);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            params.setMargins(30, 0, 0, 0);
            params.width = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.text_view_width);

            for(int i=0; i< DB.getMaterie().size(); i++)
            {
                textView = new TextView(this);
                textView.setText(DB.getMaterie().get(i).getMateria());
                textView.setBackgroundColor(DB.getMaterie().get(i).getColor());
                textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); //centro la scritta nella textview
                textView.setLayoutParams(params);   //assegno i parametri impostati sopra
                mLayout.addView(textView);
            }

        } 

        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Nessuna materia inserita
        }
    }
}//onActivityResult
```

I need to set the color dynamically from results here `materia.setMateria(result);
                materia.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.verde));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can i put all two into returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);?

You are welcome to put in two extras, using different keys (e.g., `"result"` and `"this is another extra"`).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply!
Like this?
`returnIntent.putExtra("result",result,"another",another);`
So i have two keys with two different values?

Comment: @Dario: It would require two separate calls to `putExtra()` (`returnIntent.putExtra("result",result).putExtra("another",another);`). "So i have two keys with two different values?" -- yes. The `Bundle` that underlies the `Intent` extras behaves in some respects like a `HashMap`. It is a key-value store, where the keys are strings. You can have two or more values, so long as each gets its own distinct key.

Comment: and how i take back the values?
For the String i use  `String result = data.getStringExtra("result");`
But for the color i need an integer and i can't use `int color = data.getStringExtra("color");`

Comment: @Dario: Call `getIntExtra()`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

Comment: i try to use it but he take 2 arguments (string, int).
Developer Android say `getIntExtra(String name, int defaultValue)`
defaultValue can be 1? i choose the value? i don't understand

Comment: @Dario: "defaultValue can be 1?" -- yes. "i choose the value?" -- yes.